# AWS Ubuntu java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Jama.Matrix

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, bioinformatics

I am trying to run a mutation clustering algorithm described in

https://tinyheero.github.io/2015/08/26/TrAp.html

Running `java -jar TrApWithDependencies.jar --text figure1.txt` works fine on my laptop running windows 10, but not on AWS ubuntu. I would like to run it on my AWS instance because the algorithm is very RAM hungry and will run out of memory for input data with 50 or more rows.

Running it on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS gives me the following error. I believe the key issue is with Jama.Matrix

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Jama/Matrix
    at klugerlab.trap.data.Solution.fitClones(Solution.java:703)
    at klugerlab.trap.algo.MinimalClonesSolver.processTemplate(MinimalClonesSolver.java:168)
    at klugerlab.trap.algo.MinimalClonesSolver.completeSolutions(MinimalClonesSolver.java:204)
    at klugerlab.trap.algo.MinimalClonesSolver.runSolver(MinimalClonesSolver.java:250)
    at klugerlab.trap.algo.Solver.run(Solver.java:229)
    at klugerlab.trap.algo.Job.run(Job.java:97)
    at klugerlab.trap.TrApMain.main(TrApMain.java:120)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Jama.Matrix
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 12 more
```

I do not have access to the source code, only the .jar file.

Comment: so add the jama jar to your classpath

Comment: It looks like the this application is supposed to be self-contained.  But it looks like the JARinJAR loader stuff is not working on AWS.  However you / we need source code to debug and fix this.  Since the source code is not available, I suggest you contact the programmers.  Sorry, but this is not really a programming question.

Comment: So I can't fix this by adding the jama jar to classpath? I've never worked with java before.